# Список файлов в директории и ее поддиректориях

Tags: c++

Хочу написать функцию, которая б искала файлы определенного формата в директориях и ее поддерикториях и создавала список файлов в txt файле, .... но не могу пока додуматься, как это сделать ... Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(v=VS.85).aspx).

Не уверен, что подойдет, но что вот если воспользоваться этой функцией? Имя найденного файла можно выдернуть из структуры `WIN32_FIND_DATA`, примерно будет так: вызываем FindFirstFile, находим  файл, а потом вызываем FindNextFile.

```
void Copy(LPCTSTR szInDirName, LPCTSTR szOutDirName, bool flag = false)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind;

    TCHAR szFind[MAX_PATH + 1];
    TCHAR szInFileName[MAX_PATH + 1];
    TCHAR szOutFileName[MAX_PATH + 1];

    lstrcpy(szFind, szInDirName);
    // Ищем файлы с любым именем и расширением
    lstrcat(szFind, L"\\*.*");

    hFind = FindFirstFile(szFind, &ffd);

    do
    {
        // Формируем полный путь (источник)
        lstrcpy(szInFileName, szInDirName);
        lstrcat(szInFileName, L"\\");
        lstrcat(szInFileName, ffd.cFileName);

        // Формируем полный путь (результат)
        lstrcpy(szOutFileName, szOutDirName);
        lstrcat(szOutFileName, L"\\");
        lstrcat(szOutFileName, ffd.cFileName);

        // Если flag == true, то копируем и папки
        if(flag) 
        {
            if(ffd.dwFileAttributes & 0x00000010)
            {
                if(lstrcmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") == 0 ||
                    lstrcmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") == 0) continue;

                CreateDirectory(szOutFileName, NULL);
                Copy(szInFileName, szOutFileName);
            }
        } // Иначе пропускаем папки
        else
            if(ffd.dwFileAttributes & 0x00000010) continue;

        CopyFile(szInFileName, szOutFileName, TRUE);
    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd));

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Это пример, просто, ищет файлы в одной директории, подкаталоги, копирует во вторую.

Конечно, это не так хорошо, как выше совет, но все таки работает.

Answer (score 8):

Есть библиотека [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).
В качестве примера программа выводит все файлы
с расширением cpp в текущей директории:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main() {
    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it("./"), end; it != end; ++it) {
        if (it->path().extension() == ".cpp") {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```